# MSTest unit tests and database access without touching the actual database

Tags: database, unit-testing, mstest, clone

In my code I interact with a database (not part of my solution file). The database is owned by a separate team of DBA's, and the code we developers write is only allowed to access stored procs. However we have full view of the database's procs, tables, and columns (it's definition).  For my code that is dependent upon data, I currently write unit tests that dumb-up data in the tables (and tear down/remove those rows after the unit test is done), so I can run unit tests to exercise my code that interacts with the DB. All of the code to do this is in the test file (especially in the ClassInitialize() and ClassCleanup() functions).  However I've been given some amount of grief from my new coworkers call my style of unit tests "destructive" because I read/write to the dev database inserting and removing rows. At the time we code the unit tests, the database design is generally not stable, so many times we can find issues in the stored proc code before we unleash the QA department on our programs (saves resources). They all tell me there's a way to clone to the database into memory at the time the MSTest unit tests are run, however they don't know how to do it.  I've researched around the web and cannot find a way to do what my coworkers need me to do.

**Can someone tell me for sure whether or not this can happen in the environment I shown above?  If so, can you point me in the right direction?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with a bounty, I could not find out if this does exist.  I would assume at this point, the people who had told me that this technology does exist might have been mistaken.

Answer (score 7):

Do you have SQL scripts that can be used to create your database? You should have, and they should be under version control. If so, then you can do the following:

In your **test setup code**:

- create a 'temporary' database using the SQL scripts. Use a unique name, for example unitTestDatabase_[timestamp].
- setup the data you require for your test in the test database. Ideally using public API functions (eg CreateUser, AddNewCustomer), but where the required API does not exist, use SQL commands. Using the API to set up test data makes the tests more robust against changes to the low-level implementation (i.e. database schema). Which is one reason why we write unit tests, to ensure that changes to the implementation do not break functionality.
- run your unit tests, using dependency injection to pass the test database connection string from the test code into the code under test.

and in your **test teardown code**, delete the database. Ideally should be done using your database uninstall scripts, which should also be under version control.

You can control how often you want to create a unit test database: e.g. per test project, test class or test method, or a combination, by creating the database in either an [AssemblyInitialize], [ClassInitialize] or [TestInitialize]  method.

This is a technique we use with great success. The **advantages** are:

- every time we run the unit tests, we are testing that our database installation scripts work together with the code.
- test isolation, that is the tests only affect their test database. And it doesn't matter if the rollback code goes wrong, you are not touching anyone else's data.
- Confidence in the code. That is, because we are using a real database, the unit tests give me more confidence that the code works than if I was mocking the database. Of course, this depends on how good your suite of higher level integration/component tests are.

**Disadvantages**:

- the unit tests are dependant on an external system (the DBMS). You will need to find the name of a DBMS in your test setup code. This can be done by using a config file or by looking at run time for a running local DBMS.
- Tests may be slowed down by the database installation scripts. In our experience, the  tests are still running quickly enough, and there are plenty of opportunities to optimize. We run our test suite of approx 400 unit tests in approx 1 min, which includes creating 5 separate database on a local installation of SQLServer 2008.

Comment: No, the scripts belong to the DBAs. They're a different department.  Different management.  So I'll need a tool that will reverse engineer the DB and be able to create it on the fly in memory or in a local SQL Server installation of some sort.

Thanks for the pointers on [AssemblyInitialize] and [ClassInitialize] as I can make good use of these in other unit tests  :) :)

Answer (score 4):

If you can create a 'seam' between the business logic code and your data access layer you should be ok.  Use interfaces to represent the contract your DAL exposes to your business logic and then either write your own set of Fake objects or use a mocking tool such as rhino-mocks.

If you are writing tests that hit that database then you have a huge maintenance headache, since as you state, the database is changing, and also it makes it difficult to maintain an environment that has access to the database.  What you are actually writing are integration tests, which are still valid, but true unit test's shouldnt have any dependencies on databases, file system, etc.

Comment: Yeah, we have a "seam" of sorts.  There's a DAL (seam) is made up of a static class with static functions to call atomic functions to and from the database. Not sure how to pull out an interface to static functions.  If this is integration tests, then how would we do unit tests without allowing the code to talk to the DAL?

Comment: Static = tightly coupled = unmockable (unless you use [Typemock](http://www.typemock.com/)). You would need to refactor your code to use the [Repository Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c) or some variant. Ben is correct that this will save you headaches. I highly recommend [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) over Rhino, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would mock out the database, rather than trying to interact with a test instance. This will make your tests faster (so you're more likely to run them).

Comment: Are you saying "mock" as in clone or mirror?  If so, that's what we're trying to do.  Create an in-memory version of the database for the code to interact with.  How is this done?

Comment: No, I'm saying mock as in a fake database, something that acts like a database, but you can set it's behaviour in the tests.

Comment: It would take a lot of work for me to reverse engineer the DBA's database each time I want to run the unit tests. There's a lot of complex code that happens in the DBA's stored procs as well as many many tables and columns to reproduce each time.   Is there not a tool to do this for us in VS2010?

Comment: Instead of doing this just create a class that returns some dummy data - without interacting with a database. You shouldn't need stored procs, tables or columns.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't do what the others suggested because you're actually testing the stored procedures do what you expect then I think what your colleagues are referring to is using an in-memory database.

When people talk about in-memory databases for testing they're usually referring to SQLite.   They build up the database in memory at the start of the test and destroy it at the end. Unfortunately SQLite doesn't support Stored Procedures so that won't help you.

What I would suggest is that you write specific integration tests for the Stored Procedures and insert/remove data as you currently do.  Note that it's easier if you wrap the test in a transaction that you then roll back.  You could also use the database "unit testing" features in Visual Studio for testing the sprocs if you have that available.

For the rest of your code mock your DAL as @Ben suggested and test your business logic as a normal unit test.  However, given the complexity of your DAL being a static class you're going to have to do some work to wrap the DAL and start using the wrapper class throughout your application - a little like how ASP.NET MVC deals with HttpContext.

Comment: Correct, I cannot do what the other people have suggested.  Hence the bounty I placed on this question.  I also modified the question to emphasis the question I've asked.  As noted in other replies, MOC'ing is not a good option because the DBAs are allowed to change the database sprocs, table names, column names, etc. at any time. And a MOC'd database interaction will not catch these types of subtle changes by DBAs.  A unit test that tests the current DB configuration/schema/data will be a great additional troubleshooting when our dev env goes down, quickly pinpointing the point of failure.

Comment: I don't think an in-memory-database is an option in your case. At some point you have to test your real database communication, and you should test against the real thing. You have two options as described here: Test agains a common / real database and wrap your tests inside a transaction and rollback. The other is to use a private database. If the common database is used for other purposes than testing, as it obviously is, I strongly recommend the private database approach. Then you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Can we not ask DBA to provide backup of DB and Restore it on your local machine and perform test on it.
Backup and restore is fastest way i think.